# Form does not receive KeyUp / KeyDown / KeyPress event

Tags: vb6

I have a really big app.
The form where the problem occurs has hundreds of controls and a lot of code and is being subclassed.

For some reason, they KeyPress, KeyUp and KeyDown events are not fired even though I have KeyPreview enabled.

Before I remove more and more controls to see when the problem disappears, I would like to ask if somebody has any idea what I could do to check why the events are not fired.

Thank you!

Comment: `and is being subclassed` - try removing that first?